# SQL to select multiples of a value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, json

I need to generate a candlestick graph and would need to transform this table

```
amount  created_at              updated_at
258     2019-10-17 01:45:17     2019-10-17 01:45:17
186     2019-10-17 01:45:17     2019-10-17 01:45:17
122     2019-10-17 01:46:31     2019-10-17 01:46:31
092     2019-10-17 01:46:31     2019-10-17 01:46:31
086     2019-10-17 01:47:47     2019-10-17 01:47:47
172     2019-10-17 01:47:47     2019-10-17 01:47:47
```

to the json object below

```
[
    { time: '2019-10-17 01:45:17', open: 180, high: 180, low: 178, close: 179 },
    { time: '2019-10-17 01:46:17', open: 180, high: 181, low: 177, close: 178 },
    { time: '2019-10-17 01:47:17', open: 175, high: 179, low: 175, close: 178 },
]
```

I am writing using PHP and won't mind having a PHP code that can do same thing.
Note that each time is in the interval of 5 minutes beginning from the first record in the table.

Edit:
The json values generated include `time` which is gotten from the updated_at column, the `open` which is the first data gotten from the amount for the interval, the `high` which is the highest amount for the interval, the `low` which is the lowest amount for the interval and finally the `close` which is the last data for the interval.
In a case where there is just one data, it should be used as the open, close, high and low.
All json values for this illustration are arbitrary numbers.

I have tried converting each timestamp to a unix timestamp using `strtotime()` in PHP then i looped through the values then pushed the amount into arrays if it met the condition as illustrated below.

```
$tnow = 0;
$time = 60;
$interval = 0;
$y = [];
$z = [];
$array = [];
foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 0){
        $tnow = strtotime($value['updated_at']);
    }

    if(strtotime($value['updated_at']) <= $tnow){
        array_push($z, $value['amount']);
    }
    else{
        $array = sort($z);
        $cc = count($z)-1;
        array_push($z, $z[0]);
        array_push($z, $array[$cc]);
        array_push($z, $array[0]);
        array_push($z, $z[$cc]);

        array_push($y, $z);
        $z = [];
        $tnow = ($tnow+60);
        continue;
    }
}
```

If I can achieve this better with JavaScript, I won't mind at all.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: What is summarized in the json object and how?

Comment: newadays most of the database engine support for storing json object in cell and query around it

Comment: what is quanitity and what amount? what have you tried? how do you get the wanted result from the given data? why do you have minutes slots and not five minutes in the result? are the data only one product? why is id, userid, orderid important?

Comment: It is hard to see how you derive that result from that data set, and your assertion that "each time is in the interval of 5 minutes beginning from the first record in the table" is simply untrue.

Comment: I just edited the question to reflect what I want to achieve and what I have done so far.

Comment: @cid why is my question still on hold? I have edited it to reflect what i want and what i have done so far.

Comment: True. I voted for reopening this question

Comment: @NinaScholz can you vote for reopening this question? I have editted it to reflect what i want and what i have done so far.

Comment: @Strawberry can you vote for reopening this question? I have editted it to reflect what i want and what i have done so far.

Comment: @GMB I have edited it to reflect what i want and what i have done so far.

Comment: @gnat I have edited it to reflect what i want and what i have done so far.

Comment: No, because the data set and result set still do not align, and the irritating rubbish about "5 minutes" is still there

Answer (score 0):

By having sorted data by time, you could group by minute (by just taking the part of the ISO string) and use th first value as open, and each value as end value. For getting hight and low values, you could take the maximum or minimum value.

```js
var data = [{ amount: 258, updated_at: '2019-10-17 01:45:17' }, { amount: 186, updated_at: '2019-10-17 01:45:17' }, { amount: 122, updated_at: '2019-10-17 01:46:31' }, { amount: 92, updated_at: '2019-10-17 01:46:31' }, { amount: 86, updated_at: '2019-10-17 01:47:47' }, { amount: 172, updated_at: '2019-10-17 01:47:47' }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { amount, updated_at }) => {
        var time = updated_at.slice(0, 16);
        if (!r[time]) r[time] = { time, open: amount, high: -Infinity, low: Infinity };
        r[time].high = Math.max(r[time].high, amount);
        r[time].low = Math.min(r[time].low, amount);
        r[time].close = amount;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```